# Drupal 6 user token creation?

Tags: drupal, token

In one of my project,client requirement was to send an email to registered user. and user name should be first and last name.
user first/last name token is unavailable in user setting page.

Answer (score 0):

**Drupal 6**

Install the [content profile](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_profile) module.

This module allows you to add fields to the user profile. It also includes a registration module which allows you to add extra fields to the registration form.

**Drupal 7**

You can achieve this in one of two ways:

1. Go to admin/config/people/accounts/fields and add two fields, one for first name and the other for the last name
2. Install the [Real Name](https://www.drupal.org/project/realname) module.

Comment: Are you sure this is how we need to do in drupal 6? 
As i am not able to locate anything under admin/config/people/accounts/fields

Comment: In my case i have two profile student and teacher. and it's already have first/last name field.

Comment: Sorry Jaywant, I misread the question, I've updated the answer to include Drupal 6

Comment: In my case i have two different type of user.                                                     1. Student
2. Teacher
and both are having different field to store their First/Last name